# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field MAXICODE of type Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat; in class Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;

Tags: java, android

I want to implement library of barcode scanner from https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner.
and I getting error after I run the project like this

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field MAXICODE of type Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat; in class Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat; or its >superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat' appears in /data/app/com.myPro.simantra-2/base.apk:classes3.dex)
>           at me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.(ZXingScannerView.java:54)
>           at com.myPro.ActivityMainMenu.onCreate(ActivityMainMenu.java:226)

after I debug this I find the error is while code run at

```
mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
```

but if I make a new Project and implement this, it will running well.

Comment: Then something must be different in your implementation of the library between the 2 projects. Does this error happen during compile time or during run time?
The definition of the class probably has been incompatibly changed.

Comment: @phunctional error happen during run time, when I debug I find the error is in `mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);` the different is my old project have many others library compiled rather than new project. but I confused with that errors information

Comment: If the error occurs during runtime then the definition of the class has been incompatibly changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved. the problem is in my old project/Library that Imported to current project I was compiled old

> core.jar

that doesn't contain

> MAXICODE in Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat class.

so to fix the problem just simply comment

> implementation files('libs/jars/core.jar')

in gradle. Thank you